# implementing strcpy in C

Tags: c

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  char arr[100];
  strcpy(arr, argv[1]); 
}
```

Given this, I'd like to implement the same single main method without strcpy and I have tried this.
I have tried this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  char arr[100];
  char *start = arr;

    while(*argv[1]!= '\0')
    {
        *arr= *argv[1];
        arr++;
        argv[1]++;
    }

    *destination = '\0';
    arr = start;
}
```

But this gave me an error and I am wondering why:(

Comment: `destination` is note declared here. Did you declare that outside this snippet? Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `arr = start;` is invalid because most arrays in expression (including this) are automatically converted to pointers and you cannot assign things to them.

Answer (score 1):

`arr` is not a pointer so you can't increment it. Try:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
  char arr[100];
  char *start = arr;

  while(*argv[1])
     *start++ = *argv[1]++;

  *start = 0;
  }
```

This will, of course, be a problem if `strlen(argv[1])` is greater than 99.

Answer (score 0):

Variables are just what they are. `strcpy` is classis and there's a canonical form for it.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  char arr[100];
  char *s = arr;
  char *t = argv[1];
  while ((*s++ = *t++));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a single liner from D.Ritche Book.

```
char* MY_STRCPY(char* dest, char* src)
{
    char *d = dest, *s = src;
    while(*d++ = *s++);
    return dest;
}
```